# Get LI Data ID's from Dynamic Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the closest UL elements then LI data id, but the button does nothing, no errors, which suggests its not finding the elements.

The purpose of this, is the user enters the number of vans they have available for the day, then drag and drop each delivery under each van. The user will then click on create dropsheet and it will print of a PDF for those items only in the assigned van.

For now i only need the create dropsheet to alert the data ids so i can then pass them to AJAX.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#vans').on('input', function() {
    vansDo();
    doMap();
  });

  function vansDo() {
    var vans = $('#vans').val();
    var drops = $("#placeVans").html('<br /><p class="text-center">Drag each booking onto the required vehicle. Move each booking into delivery position. Then print off drop sheets for each vehicle.</p>');
    if (vans >= '1') {
      for (i = 1; i <= vans; i++) {
        drops = $("#placeVans").html();
        $("#placeVans").html(drops + '<div id="van' + i + '" class="col-lg-4"><h3 class="align-center"><i class="fa fa-truck"></i> Van ' + i + '</h3><ul id="sortable2" class="droptrue c-white bg-gray"></ul><a data-toggle="modal" data-id="' + i + '" data-target="#modal-map" class="btn btn-primary m-t-10 m-r-10"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> View Map</a><a class="dropsheet btn btn-primary m-t-10"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Create Dropsheet</a></div>');
      };
    } else {
      $("#placeVans").html(drops_default);
    }
    sortinit();
    $("#sortable1").html(cache).sortable("refresh");
    $("#sortable2").disableSelection();
  }

  $('#placeVans').on('click', '.dropsheet', function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').each(function() {
      alert($(this).data('id'));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">
  <li data-id="1" class="sortable col-md-12 m-b-10 p-t-10 p-b-10 bd-3 bg-opacity-20 fade in">1</li>
  <li data-id="2" class="sortable col-md-12 m-b-10 p-t-10 p-b-10 bd-3 bg-opacity-20 fade in">2</li>
  <li data-id="3" class="sortable col-md-12 m-b-10 p-t-10 p-b-10 bd-3 bg-opacity-20 fade in">3</li>
  <li data-id="4" class="sortable col-md-12 m-b-10 p-t-10 p-b-10 bd-3 bg-opacity-20 fade in">4</li>
</ul>


<div id="placeVans" class="row m-b-20"></div>
```

So i need the following part to work, the LI is dragged from sortable1 to sortable2.

```
$('#placeVans').on('click', '.dropsheet', function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').each(function() {
      alert($(this).data('id'));
    });
  });
```

Comment: What is `.dropsheet`? There seems to be some code missing. It would also help a lot to see a working example of the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Its the class for the a href, located in the $("#placeVans").html() within the function vansDo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `a` element ie: the button is not inside your `ul` tag . So your `$(this).closest('ul')` will not work. But the `ul` is wrapped under the same parent as `a` tag so you can do this.

```
 $('#placeVans').on('click', '.dropsheet', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul.droptrue').find('li').each(function() {
      alert($(this).data('id'));
    });
  });
```

the change is in this part `$(this).parent().find('ul.droptrue')`.

Also taking from your code. `$("#placeVans").html(.....` there is no `li` tags inside your `ul`. here `<ul id="sortable2" class="droptrue c-white bg-gray"></ul>` Not sure if this is intentional. Just pointing out.

Comment: The li tags are in sortable 1. The user drags from sortable 1 to sortable 2. Thus in sortable 2 is where i need the data from. But your code works great! Thank you

Comment: If this helped you resolve your issue then please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `ul` is not an ancestor of the `button`, instead it is a sibling so

```
  $('#placeVans').on('click', '.dropsheet', function() {
    //$(this).closest('div').find('ul li').each(function() {})
    $(this).siblings('ul').find('li').each(function() {
      alert($(this).data('id'))
    })
  });
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you. Both yours and @reddy code works.